# Выбор элемента на странице jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

Как получить "сектор приз"? Мой вариант не работает, уже запутался в этих скобках

```
 <tr id="tr-345">
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Сектор приз</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>    

console.log($("tr#tr-345":nth-child(4)).value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#output").text($("#tr-345 th:nth-child(3)").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
<tr id="tr-345">
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Сектор приз</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>    
</table>

Output:<span id="output"></span>
```